# How can i insert memory info in a different layout in a textview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have an application with a swipe view and I have more tabs.xml not a single main.xml. For this reason if I want display something in a textview for example in the second tab I wrote this part:

```
public static class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);

        int tabLayout = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        tabLayout = R.layout.tab1;
        break;
        case 1:
        tabLayout = R.layout.tab2;
        break;
        case 2:
        tabLayout = R.layout.tab3;
        break;
        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);

        if (tabLayout == R.layout.tab2) {    
            TextView CPUinfo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CPUinfo);
            CPUinfo.setText(getCPUinfo());

        }    
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Everything goes well. Now... I have this code for the memory info:

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) appContext.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
```

And I want to display it in a textview (where the id could be `memoryinfos`) for example always in the second tab. I tried to put this code into `if (tabLayout == R.layout.tab2)`but I always get an error in `getSystemService` . How can i do?

Comment: If you get an error, please give us some logcat. Also, I'm not sure to understand your question...

Comment: The error is in the java. `The method getSystemService(String) is` `undefined` Just only want display in a textview placed in the tab2 the memoryinfo